# My computer has no place for a keyboard cord

Tags: keyboard, ps2

I have a dell d630 laptop and I recently bought a Microsoft Natural Multimedia Keyboard 1.0a. When I looked over my computer for a place to plug the cord in, however, I couldn't find one. The end of the cord has a circle of dots with a small plastic rectangle in the middle. Do most computers have a place to put this kind of cord, or is it outdated or something? Is there anything I can do to get the keyboard to work? Is there some kind of cord I can buy to make this work with a USB port?

Comment: now i feel old :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That type of cord is called a PS/2 cord and yes, it has been superseded by USB.
You can find an adapter at any electronics store, or online. (You're looking for a "PS/2 to USB adapter")

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a PS/2 connector. PS/2-keyboards are not outdated, as they are still widely used for their performance benefits, e.g. full n-key rollover, but have been superseded by USB as a de facto standard, largely in favour of compatibility. Compatibility is still good enough that 'dumb' PS/2-USB-adapters for keyboards almost always work for keyboards and mice.
[image: PS/2-USB-adapter]

Comment: Almost always. This only works if the keyboard 'speaks' both USB and PS/2 and it auto detects when you use such a plug. What you really want is an active converter, or a Lattitude D series dockingstation.

Comment: Have had issues with some adapters not working in the past.  Microsoft used to ship an adapter with Keyboards and mice.  Third party ones were hit and miss